# How to check which mln is in write suspend mode

Tags: db2, db2-luw

My database has 8 partitions (mlns) How to check which mls is in write suspend mode? I can get the status usnig following command:

```
export DB2NODE=0;db2 connect to BLUDB;db2 get db cfg for BLUDB
```

But this needs to be executed 8 times for each DB2NODE. Is there a single command which can get me which mlns are in write suspend mode and which are not?

Answer (score 1):

You tagged db2-400, did you mean db2-luw?

You can do the check either via command-lines (e.g. when scripting) or with SQL.

For scripting, Db2-LUW has two commands that may help, look in the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.partition.doc/doc/c0005829.html) online, they are `db2_all` and `rah`

If you prefer SQL, many database functions have a parameter for MEMBER which if set to -2 means all active members, and DBPARTITIONNUM if using DPF. So you could use [DB_GET_CFG](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0022028.html#r0022028__view_22028) function for parameter 'suspend_io' for member=-2.

For example:

```
SELECT NAME, VARCHAR(VALUE, 20) AS VALUE, MEMBER,
   DBPARTITIONNUM FROM TABLE(SYSPROC.DB_GET_CFG(-2))
   WHERE NAME ='suspend_io' ORDER BY NAME, MEMBER;
```